# How to find maximum of two or more parametric functions?

Tags: parametric-functions, maximum

I have two parametric functions in which I know the range of parameters and I want to find the maximum of these two functions by conditions on the value of the variable. Suppose $f(x)=x-c$ and $g(x)=r.x+(1-r).\max\{x,x-p+0.5\}$ where $0<r<1$ and $0\le p \le1$. I want to find $h(x)= f(x) I\{f(x)\ge g(x)\} + g(x) (1-I\{f(x)\ge g(x)\})     $ by conditioning on values of $p$ and $r$. Moreover, how is it possible to find $\int_{0}^{1}h(x) dx$

Comment: but h(x) doesn't depend on x.

Comment: I think you can also change your title since it is not a `Maximize` problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

```
f[x_, c_] := x - c;
g[x_, r_, p_] := r*x + (1 - r)*Max[x, x - p + 1/2];
h[x_, r_, p_, c_] := 
  f[x, c]*Boole[f[x, c] >= g[x, r, p]] + 
    g[x, r, p] (1 - Boole[f[x, c] >= g[x, r, p]]) // Simplify;
h[x, r, p, c]
Integrate[h[x, r, p, c], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < r < 1 && 0 <= p <= 1]
```

**Edit**

In the original question, $\mathrm{Max}_{0\leq x\leq 1} \{f(x),g(x)\}$  does not depend on $x$,so $h(x)$ only depend on $r$ and $p$ and $c$, and we have to treat $\mathrm{Max} \{f(x),g(x)\}$  instead of $\mathrm{Max}_{0\leq x\leq 1} \{f(x),g(x)\}$

```
f[x_, c_] := x - c;
g[x_, r_, p_] := r*x + (1 - r)*Max[x, x - p + 1/2];
Integrate[Max[f[x, c], g[x, r, p]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < r < 1 && 0 <= p <= 1]
```

**Original**

Perhaps this.

```
f[x_, c_] := x - c;
g[x_, r_, p_] := r*x + (1 - r)*Max[x, x - p + 1/2]; 
Maximize[{Max[f[x, c], 
   g[x, r, p]], 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 < r < 1 && 0 <= p <= 1}, x]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this code provides $\max_x h(x)$. Actually, what I am looking for is just $h(x)$. For example, if $c\le x \le c-rp+0.5$, then the code returns $h(x)=x-c$.

Comment: @Katatonia In your question, `h[x]` is the Maximum of `f[x]` and `g[x]` in  the interval `[0,1]`, so it is only depend on` r,p,c`, but does not depend on `x`.

Comment: oo. You are right. Should I change it as $h(x) = f(x). I\{ f(x) \ge g(x)  \} + g(x) (1-I\{ f(x) \ge g(x)  \}   )$

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I know if there is any way to get exact conditions instead of True?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]
f[x_, c_] := x - c;
g[x_, r_, p_] := r*x + (1 - r)*Max[x, x - p + 1/2];
```

You can use [`PiecewiseExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html):

```
h[x_, r_, p_, c_] := FullSimplify @ PiecewiseExpand @ Max[f[x, c], g[x, r, p]]

h[x, r, p, c]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[h[x, r, p, c], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Does 'True' mean otherwise? If the first two conditions are not satisfied, then, the third case is true?

Comment: @Katatonia, right.

Comment: Can I know why conditions do not depend on $x$? I thought that conditions should be defined based on thresholds on $x$ where thresholds are functions of parameters $r$, $p$, and $c$. And, How, is it possible to find the integration of $h(x)$ as I edited the question?

Comment: @Katatonia, the conditions do not depend on x because of the special structure of  your `f` and `g` (because the term `x` is common, it drops out in all comparisons). If you had, for example, `f[x_, c_] := 2 x - c` then the conditions would depend on  `x`.